# Storing and Retrieving User Input

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

How to store user input from multiple pages and retrieve/display back user data on another html page

I am making a voting system and I needed help storing my results. Currently using local storage in JavaScript. Please do not recommended using data base as the deadline for the project is in 4 days.

So the main problem is whenever a user enters his/her preferences for a candidate the preferences are directly stored on another html page, but as soon as the second user enters his/her preferences the preferences by the first candidate disappears and the preferences for the second candidate gets stored.
I need to store preferences from every user to the html page. I need a efficient way to store my results in.

My local storage code

```
//store//
            localStorage.setItem("preference1", selection[i].value);


// retrieve //
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

            const key = localStorage.key(i);
            const value = localStorage.getItem(key);

            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += `${key}: ${value} <br>`;

        }
```

Comment: Well ... A database is the only reliable solution, but you can store the results in a .json file on your server as well.

Comment: If security is not an issue, and everyone is using the same browser like you suggest, there's no reason why local storage can't hold multiple different users data.

Comment: @DBS can you help me if I post my code?

Comment: Possibly, if you include a minimal example then you are much more likely to get productive answers.

Comment: @DBS I have posted the code, this part of the code does not allow multiple user input storage, this only allows in one user input to be stored

Comment: Instead of storing one preference per local storage key, I would suggest building an array of objects. Each object would contain the data for one user. Then you can just keep pushing to that array for each user.

Comment: @DBS Is this within the part of localstorage?

Comment: @DBS And will this store the user input permanently (like if we press refresh or close the tab, will it still display the stored data)?

Comment: Local storage is as permanent as any data in a users browser can be, and it can be accessed the next time the page loads. It can technically be removed in a number of ways, but unless you are prepared to have a server-side data storage, local storage is the best option you have.

Comment: @DBS Is array of objects a part of local storage?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is covering how you can add multiple "sets" of data to local storage (it is not secure and only works for a single browser):

- Build an object containing all of the preferences for the current user
- Push these into an array that will be stored in local storage
- When saving the array, use `JSON.stringify` to convert the array to a string
- When retrieving the array (as a string), convert it back using `JSON.parse`

(As localstorage is not allowed inside stack snippets, check this identical [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc5kjerp/) to see it working)

```js
// Keeping your key in a variable is generally good practice
// so it's easy to change and immune to typos
const localStorageKey = 'preferences'

function addNew() {
  // Build an object containing all the prefernces for the current user
  var preferences = {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C',
  }
  // Load the existing data
  var existingData = load()
  // Push the new users data to the data
  existingData.push(preferences)
  // Save the data
  save(existingData)
}

function load() {
  // Get the saved data from local storage
  var existing = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey)
  if (existing) {
    // If the data exists, parse it back into an array
    existing = JSON.parse(existing)
  } else {
    // If this is the first time, create an empty array
    existing = []
  }
  // Return the array with any previous data included
  return existing
}

function save(data) {
  // Save data to local storage, converting the JS array to a string first
  localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(data))
}

// Adding events to the example buttons
document.getElementById("example1").onclick = addNew
document.getElementById("example2").onclick = function() {
  var currentSave = load()
  console.log(currentSave)
}
```

```html
<button id="example1">Add new users data</button>
<button id="example2">Print out currently saved data</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on this and ask you if my code has any bugs regarding the code :)